# Recycler View is Empty in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to parse JSON data and display it in a fragment using `RecyclerView`. However, when I run that app, I am getting a blank screen. I have done this code first time using an `Activity` which worked perfectly. Then I converted it to a `Fragment`. In the `Fragment` it shows a blank screen.

Here's the code of my `Fragment`

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ExampleAdapter mExampleAdapter;
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(requireActivity());
        parseJson();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void parseJson(){
        String url ="http://maranamassapp.cf/json_getdata.php";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("server_response");
                            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject ser =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String creatorname =  ser.getString("filmname");
                                String imageUrl = ser.getString("filmimage");
                                String cat = ser.getString("filmcat");

                                mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(imageUrl,creatorname,cat));
                            }

                            mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(getContext(),mExampleList);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

And the Adapter Code

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder>{
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    public ExampleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ExampleItem> examplelist){
        mContext =context;
        mExampleList = examplelist;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.example_item,parent,false);
        return new ExampleViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);
        String imageUrl = currentItem.getmImageUrl();
        String creatorName = currentItem.getmCreator();
        String cat =currentItem.getmCat();

        holder.mTextViewCreator.setText(creatorName);
        holder.mTextViewCat.setText(cat);
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(holder.mImageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();
    }

    public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mTextViewCreator;
        public TextView mTextViewCat;
        public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            mTextViewCreator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_creator);
            mTextViewCat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_cat);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting the response from server correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you implement the `RecyclerView` like the following.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(requireActivity());

    // Set the adapter here. 
    // Use getActivity() instead of getContext()
    mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(getContext(),mExampleList);

    parseJson();
    return rootView;
}

private void parseJson(){
    String url ="http://maranamassapp.cf/json_getdata.php";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("server_response");
                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject ser =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String creatorname =  ser.getString("filmname");
                            String imageUrl = ser.getString("filmimage");
                            String cat = ser.getString("filmcat");

                            mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(imageUrl,creatorname,cat));
                        }

                        // Just call notifyDataSetChanged here 
                        mExampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Note that, I set the adapter in the `onCreateView` passing `getActivity()` as context instead of `getContext`. In the `parseJson` function, I am just calling `notifyDataSetChanged` when the `mExampleList` is updated with newly added data.

Also, check if you are getting the response from your server correctly and you are not getting any exception while parsing the response.

Hope this works!

Comment: Still, It is not showing anything. My server is working fine. Now It is showing a warning at <  private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;  >The Warning Says field can be converted to a local variable. Thanks For Your Support.